# How can I configure ssh client to open tmux by default only when ssh is called without parameters?

Tags: ssh

I do want to use tmux by default when I am establshing ssh connection and this works well with a command like:

```
ssh host.example.com -t 'tmux a || tmux || /bin/bash'
```

I can even put this as part of the ProxyCommand inside the `~/.ssh/config` but the problem is that I am also doing SSH connections as part of scripts that are just running different commands on the remote machines and I do not want tmux in this case.

How can I achieve this behaviour so tmux invocation would be transparent and happen only when ssh is colled without any paramerts / commands.

Answer (score 1):

You're re-inventing the wheel.

- Install [Byobo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_(software)).
- `byobu-enable`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
function ssh() {
  if [ "$#" == "1" ]; then
    if [ "${1:0:1}" != "-" ]; then
      /usr/bin/ssh "$@" -t 'tmux a || tmux || /bin/bash'
    else
    /usr/bin/ssh "$@";
    fi
  else
    /usr/bin/ssh "$@";
  fi
}
```